# ModelForm instance with ForeignKey - unexpected behaviour

Tags: django, foreign-keys

The Model:

```
class Person(Models.model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  father =  models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name="father", null=True, blank=True)
  mother = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name="mother", null=True, blank=True)
```

The Form:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
      if instance.name !='':
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

      logger.debug("father %s" % instance.father.all())

  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('name')
```

My intention is to check if the instance has a father, so I add `logger.debug`, to see what is in `instance.father.all()` (I wasn't sure if it is None or '' or sth else).

When I looked into the log, I saw that `instance.father.all()` gets no father of instance person, but persons which father is instance Person!

To clarify: let's assume, that instance Person is me. I want to get my father, but I get my children (I get people, who have me as father)

Very nice (I'll use it later), but I still don't know how to get father of instance Person... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
logger.debug("father %s" % instance.father.all())
```

you call the related name `father` and you naturally get all children of this person.

Change the related names to something else, maybe `fathers_children` and `mothers_children`, so you don't get confused.

If you want to get the father of a person, e.g. the current instance of the class Person, you should try the following line:

```
logger.debug("father %s" % instance.father)
```

which will return an object.

You can also do:

```
logger.debug("father %s" % instance.father_id)
```

to get the id of the father.

Nicer is to format the strings like this:

```
logger.debug('father {0}'.format(instance.father))
```

A child can have only one father and one mother, but a father (or mother) can have many children. So calling something like `instance.father.all()` doesn't make a lot of sense. That would be like getting all fathers of the child, where it is only one.

Comment: What did you read fast? I'm just curious. Nevertheless it's nice we quickly found the solution. Please also check your answer, I edited some typos and little grammar errors.

Comment: First I read your answer and didn't find the solution (read just code) nad miss your explanation, and see answer useless. After that I read it again but whole and saw, that its very good explanation - so I remove my poor answer and mark yours